# Getting different thread order even time I run my program

Tags: java, multithreading

can someone tell me the order in which a thread starts to execute?. I have written the following code

```
class NewThread implements Runnable {
    Thread t;
    NewThread() {
        //creating a second thread.
        t=new Thread(this,"Demo Thread");
        System.out.println("Child Thread:"+t);
        t.start();
    }

    public void run() {
        try {
            for(int i=0;i<5;i++) {
                System.out.println("Child Thread:"+i);
                Thread.sleep(3000);
            }
        } catch(Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e.getLocalizedMessage());
        }
        System.out.println("Exiting Child Thread");
    }
}
```

and this

```
public class ThreadDemo {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        new NewThread();
        try {
            for(int i=0;i<5;i++) {
                System.out.println("Main Thread:"+i);
                Thread.sleep(3000);
            }
        } catch(Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e.getLocalizedMessage());
        }
        System.out.println("Exiting Main Thread");
    }
}
```

when I execute this code, I get many different sets of output.

```
Child Thread:Thread[Demo Thread,5,main]
Main Thread:0
Child Thread:0
Child Thread:1
Main Thread:1
Main Thread:2
Child Thread:2
Main Thread:3
Child Thread:3
Main Thread:4
Child Thread:4
Exiting Main Thread
Exiting Child Thread
```

another one,

```
Child Thread:Thread[Demo Thread,5,main]
Main Thread:0
Child Thread:0
Child Thread:1
Main Thread:1
Child Thread:2
Main Thread:2
Child Thread:3
Main Thread:3
Child Thread:4
Main Thread:4
Exiting Child Thread
Exiting Main Thread
```

Why is this occurring? Will the thread order never be same?? and it would be nice, if someone can give me pointers to basics of threading and examples.
P.S: I am new to threads and this is my first thread program. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Nobody can. They're threads. They run at the same time. If you want sequential execution why use threads at all?

Comment: It is out of control of your program, and you can't predict the order.

Comment: Short answer is that it's undefined. But this is a tricky and big subject, and not one well-suited for learning piecemeal on SO. I'd recommend getting a copy of JCIP.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> when I execute this code, I get many different sets of output.

This is expected.  The order is not defined and is subject to race conditions as the threads start running and are subjected to thread scheduling by the OS.

The whole reason why we write multi-threaded applications is that the threads are asynchronous and run in separate processors for speed reasons.   To guarantee specific output order, you could synchronize between the threads with locks and the like but you would then lose performance and the whole reason for forking threads would be diminished.

Comment: Should I use thread synchronization to follow a predefined order and can you provide some pointers for the same. Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you explain _why_ you want the order to be a certain way?  The whole point of the threads is to run in parallel in separate processors and not be lock-stepped with other threads.

Comment: I'f you're planning to write a multithreaded application, you should be embracing arbitrary orderings of events for as much of your program as possible, except for a few specific orderings or invariants.

Comment: hi @Gray- Does "thread scheduling algorithm" MEAN that the OS DECIDES which thread starts its execution first (based on many factors such as memory, cpu, etc.) and therefore DOES NOT DEPEND ON US (it is non-deterministic)? we don't know which thread will finish first either, do we? Thanks in advace

Comment: That's correct @Daniel.  The whole point of programming in threads is the asynchronous nature of it.  If it was deterministic it would be much slower and have less concurrency.

Comment: great @Gray +1 and marked as a USEFUL answer. One last question, Even if you use synchronization mechanisms, at the end of the day, are they still INDEPENDENT (one thread should not KNOW what the other is doing and vice versa) and IN PARALLEL? Since my understanding is that synchronization ONLY REDUCES parallelism, yet they are still running in parallel.

Comment: `synchronization` doesn't necessarily reduce anything.  It just ensures (if done correctly) that one thread can work on a protected piece of code at one time and it ensures appropriate memory publishing.  If there is a lot of thread contention for a particular `synchronize` block then you might get serial thread execution but any non-synchronized blocks or if there are multiple synchronized areas locking on different objects then you will continue to see concurrency.

Comment: "If there is a lot of thread contention for a particular synchronize block then you might get serial thread execution" - would that happen because one THREAD is WAITING for the LOCK that the other one has to be RELEASED, right?

Comment: Yes @Daniel.  If you look at a thread dump from a running application you can see threads that are in WAIT or BLOCKED states as opposed to RUNNING.  See: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/lifecycle-and-states-of-a-thread-in-java/

Comment: Great, thank you very much master in multithreading @Gray, my doubts are now solved, +1

Comment: All of your doubts are solved?  Wow.  Wish I could say the same. ;-)  Have a good one.

Comment: Haha :), well TO A CERTAIN POINT I meant. Nobody never FINISH learning, greetings from here, from Mexico.

Answer (score 0):

You have encountered a race condition.

You have stumbled across one of the complexities of multi-threading.  If you have code that MUST be processed in a particular order you must "lock" that code and/or declare variables within it "volatile".  Run a google search for "deadlocks" and "race conditions".

Answer (score 0):

There is no implicit order. If you must have an order, use the ExecutorService with a que depth of 1.

Comment: *ExecutorService with a que depth of 1.* will work only if there is a single thread too.